# Echo all the columns starting from 3rd column using Batch script

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file

I'm trying to echo and set variable a value by reading a text file.  I have a problem that data line contains double quotes in it and the output doesn't come out well as expected.

test.txt file contains:

```
call m2srun "AB test 1.csv"
call m2srun "AB test 2.csv"
call m2srun "AB test 3.csv"
```

Code that I've tried:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in (test.txt) do echo %%a
```

Actual Output:

```
"AB
"AB
"AB
```

But I'm expecting an output like..

```
"AB test 1.csv"
"AB test 2.csv"
"AB test 3.csv"
```

Note: The csv names are not fixed length.  It contains spaces and can be any longer.

Comment: Why not use the doublequote character as your delimiter and select the second token? e.g. `@For /F UseBackTokens^=2Delims^=^" %%A In ("test.txt") Do @Echo "%%A"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2,* delims= " %%a in (test.txt) do echo %%b
```

May work for you - it depends on whether the first 2 columns may also contain quoted strings that may contain spaces. The `*` means "the rest of the line following the highest-numbered token specified".

Comment: Great! it worked.  Could you explain the %%b part please?  We are reading the test.txt file and storing the contents on %%a but how %%b gives the right answer?

Comment: If you read the `for/f` documentation, then you'll find you can specify a set of tokens, separated by commas. The lowest-numbered token from your selection arrives in the selected `metavariable`, in this case, `%%a`. The next-highest goes to `%%b` and so on. Token `*` delivers the remainder of the line after the highest selected-token number as if it was a token number.